# Problem with the fit of Gradient Boosting after test the data in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost, gbm

Currently I'm working with a GBM model (Gradient Boosting Machine) to predict some rate calls **TIIE**.

I split my data in 2 parts: **train set** and **test set**. After I train my data with the `gbm()` function of the `xgboost package` as follows

```
    gbm.fit<-gbm(formula=TIIE~.,
             distribution="gaussian", 
             data=BD_train,
             n.trees=20000,
             interaction.depth=6, 
             shrinkage=0.001,
             cv.folds=5,
             n.cores=NULL)
```

I predicted with the `predict()` function and my **test data**. The result had an incredible fit, but when I tried to predict with another data I didn't get the same result. Someone knows what is happening or what I'm doing wrong?

```
prediction<-predict.gbm(object=gbm.fit,
                          newdata=BD_test)
```

The data is:

```
structure(list(TIIE_2Y = c(4.975, 4.97, 5, 5.01, 4.977, 4.95, 
4.975, 4.965, 5.001, 5.06, 5.07, 5.04, 5.025, 5.03, 5.04, 4.955, 
4.855, 4.82, 4.83, 4.83, 4.64, 4.685, 4.63, 4.665, 4.685, 4.69, 
4.615, 4.63, 4.62, 4.64, 4.645, 4.689, 4.67, 4.646, 4.79, 4.807, 
4.81, 4.81, 4.86, 4.855, 4.86, 4.87, 4.86, 4.795, 4.79, 4.787, 
4.8, 4.815, 4.805, 4.83, 4.8, 4.805, 4.77, 4.74, 4.731, 4.785, 
4.78, 4.8, 4.771, 4.765, 4.76, 4.75, 4.753, 4.77, 4.78, 4.79, 
4.801, 4.785, 4.77, 4.75, 4.72, 4.735, 4.795, 4.72, 4.72, 4.68, 
4.701, 4.65, 4.641, 4.68, 4.7, 4.705, 4.74, 4.705, 4.72, 4.715, 
4.775, 4.785, 4.8, 4.819, 4.795, 4.828, 4.865, 4.875, 4.87, 4.84, 
4.84, 4.822, 4.835, 4.845, 4.845, 4.845, 4.835, 4.831, 4.843, 
4.885, 4.89, 4.9, 4.932, 4.925, 4.93, 4.905, 4.893, 4.87, 4.859, 
4.85, 4.871, 4.87, 4.91, 4.945, 4.91, 4.9, 4.91, 4.908, 4.908, 
4.91, 4.91, 4.92, 4.925, 4.94, 4.97, 4.98, 4.975, 4.98, 4.985, 
4.995, 5.039, 5.04, 5.08, 5.1, 5.12, 5.1, 5.075, 5.057, 5.01, 
5.01, 5.005, 5.02, 5.03, 5.035, 5.015, 5.02, 5.015, 5.03, 5.035, 
5.05, 5.035, 5.05, 4.995, 4.995, 4.979, 4.995, 4.97, 4.98, 4.99, 
4.99, 5.005, 5.02, 5.025, 5, 4.9925, 4.993, 4.995, 4.99, 4.99, 
5.005, 5.005, 5.01, 4.98, 4.955, 4.937, 4.9, 4.739, 4.75, 4.75, 
4.725, 4.702, 4.685, 4.67, 4.59, 4.565, 4.555, 4.62, 4.63, 4.575, 
4.57, 4.58, 4.58, 4.575, 4.54, 4.53, 4.58, 4.58, 4.574, 4.545, 
4.52, 4.535, 4.515, 4.485, 4.485, 4.495, 4.495, 4.485, 4.485, 
4.5, 4.51, 4.5, 4.485, 4.49, 4.465, 4.45, 4.42, 4.38, 4.34, 4.34, 
4.29, 4.275, 4.24, 4.26, 4.23, 4.24, 4.26, 4.273, 4.195, 4.19, 
4.195, 4.185, 4.1025, 4.155, 4.175, 4.2, 4.178, 4.14, 4.17, 4.17, 
4.2, 4.276, 4.355, 4.46, 4.42, 4.355, 4.551, 4.73, 4.678, 4.58, 
4.545, 4.576, 4.68, 4.76, 5.016, 4.82, 4.836, 4.817, 4.72, 4.7, 
4.71, 4.75, 4.749, 4.84, 4.75, 4.62, 4.635, 4.62, 4.518, 4.555, 
4.57, 4.525, 4.48, 4.515, 4.57, 4.66, 4.72, 4.749, 4.73, 4.61, 
4.63, 4.57, 4.51, 4.49, 4.52, 4.64, 4.68, 4.75, 4.83, 4.72, 4.7, 
4.714, 4.633, 4.675, 4.69, 4.75, 4.75, 4.761, 4.781, 4.739, 4.319, 
4.283, 4.238, 4.195, 4.2, 4.1164, 4.073, 4.094, 4.16, 4.19, 4.185, 
4.135, 4.074, 4.076, 4.075, 4.13, 4.1, 3.935, 3.98, 3.99, 3.935, 
3.952, 3.99, 4.22, 4.21, 4.208, 4.232, 4.22, 4.24, 4.26, 4.245, 
4.23, 4.187, 4.235, 4.22, 4.213, 4.21, 4.2, 4.154, 4.18, 4.229, 
4.23, 4.215, 4.185, 4.175, 4.16, 4.15, 4.166, 4.14, 4.16, 4.19, 
4.22, 4.268, 4.268, 4.275, 4.26, 4.266, 4.285, 4.295, 4.32, 4.43, 
4.375, 4.343, 4.37, 4.37, 4.37, 4.36, 4.379, 4.37, 4.37, 4.37, 
4.48, 4.5, 4.495, 4.43, 4.42, 4.35, 4.35, 4.35, 4.32, 4.282, 
4.33, 4.301, 4.285, 4.283, 4.29, 4.29, 4.262, 4.28, 4.285, 4.276, 
4.278, 4.3, 4.29, 4.29, 4.349, 4.35, 4.332, 4.29, 4.31, 4.285, 
4.315, 4.315, 4.27, 4.254, 4.24, 4.24, 4.25, 4.266, 4.27, 4.27, 
4.282, 4.273, 4.24, 4.233, 4.24, 4.285, 4.292, 4.279, 4.279, 
4.245, 4.24, 4.241, 4.255, 4.24, 4.23, 4.2275, 4.23, 4.21, 4.2, 
4.1875, 4.187, 4.2, 4.195, 4.19, 4.21, 4.225, 4.245, 4.248, 4.207, 
3.817, 3.84, 3.829, 3.81, 3.82), INF = c(0.041039205, 0.04092598, 
0.040699857, 0.040360831, 0.040247821, 0.040134846, 0.039913084, 
0.039419821, 0.03922756, 0.039035357, 0.03788247, 0.037690455, 
0.037177844, 0.037177146, 0.037176674, 0.037176193, 0.037174768, 
0.03717407, 0.037173118, 0.037172645, 0.037164895, 0.037158315, 
0.037166112, 0.037174126, 0.037181922, 0.037205742, 0.037213535, 
0.037221546, 0.037229339, 0.037237348, 0.03726093, 0.037369002, 
0.037477078, 0.037250679, 0.035892985, 0.035666823, 0.035440859, 
0.03476278, 0.034537143, 0.034171737, 0.033806604, 0.033826519, 
0.033906143, 0.033946158, 0.033966052, 0.034025928, 0.03404581, 
0.034065682, 0.034649261, 0.03523338, 0.035942619, 0.036119836, 
0.036474518, 0.037006981, 0.037184494, 0.037717322, 0.03740902, 
0.037787746, 0.037977139, 0.038166554, 0.038735162, 0.039114422, 
0.039303972, 0.039493764, 0.040221006, 0.040426448, 0.040631906, 
0.040837388, 0.041453896, 0.041865196, 0.04207076, 0.042276557, 
0.042805122, 0.042849343, 0.042894221, 0.043027441, 0.043072044, 
0.043161218, 0.043205559, 0.043338973, 0.04330962, 0.04328005, 
0.043376047, 0.043520095, 0.043616103, 0.043664183, 0.043712025, 
0.043856076, 0.04390428, 0.044108302, 0.044122841, 0.044087486, 
0.044052355, 0.043911236, 0.04387592, 0.043811904, 0.043884526, 
0.043917525, 0.04395052, 0.043983512, 0.0440165, 0.044115889, 
0.044148863, 0.044181834, 0.044214801, 0.044247983, 0.044453186, 
0.044615732, 0.044778049, 0.044940812, 0.045591853, 0.045754611, 
0.04591714, 0.046080115, 0.04624287, 0.04658711, 0.046605171, 
0.046631519, 0.04665785, 0.046763772, 0.046816787, 0.046843066, 
0.046869327, 0.046948739, 0.04707907, 0.047209609, 0.047266158, 
0.047323148, 0.047493427, 0.047550181, 0.04760692, 0.047663881, 
0.047720621, 0.047947728, 0.047647936, 0.047348145, 0.047241657, 
0.046923097, 0.046816688, 0.046710359, 0.046604112, 0.046497709, 
0.046179184, 0.045966853, 0.045860464, 0.046110771, 0.046228651, 
0.046162353, 0.046096277, 0.04602998, 0.045963699, 0.045765094, 
0.04569905, 0.045632786, 0.045566754, 0.043992487, 0.043870158, 
0.043625259, 0.043502913, 0.043135408, 0.043013409, 0.042890897, 
0.042646073, 0.04338612, 0.042899721, 0.041685081, 0.041442444, 
0.041199637, 0.040956894, 0.039318078, 0.039168061, 0.039018138, 
0.038868302, 0.038418704, 0.038268803, 0.038118997, 0.037969285, 
0.037220564, 0.0370789, 0.036685213, 0.035677672, 0.035174067, 
0.034168042, 0.033916759, 0.033526989, 0.033388833, 0.033071666, 
0.032965814, 0.032754441, 0.032648496, 0.032225984, 0.03212025, 
0.032014551, 0.031908894, 0.03178987, 0.031847657, 0.031962935, 
0.032135979, 0.03225164, 0.03236698, 0.032871682, 0.03314814, 
0.033286454, 0.033424537, 0.03383935, 0.034116248, 0.03425446, 
0.034392875, 0.03496932, 0.035077544, 0.035185986, 0.035294224, 
0.035727237, 0.035835719, 0.035943998, 0.036052276, 0.036619485, 
0.03723123, 0.037536857, 0.038454905, 0.039680396, 0.04060037, 
0.041370103, 0.04154091, 0.042053222, 0.042224389, 0.042395112, 
0.043249988, 0.043421049, 0.043592086, 0.044099925, 0.044325575, 
0.045003269, 0.045228983, 0.045455043, 0.045681008, 0.046812044, 
0.047264511, 0.047100951, 0.046820928, 0.046727625, 0.04663434, 
0.046540852, 0.046167937, 0.046074757, 0.045981374, 0.04588844, 
0.046286184, 0.046632448, 0.046892386, 0.046979059, 0.047238716, 
0.046940524, 0.046824174, 0.046708063, 0.046591981, 0.046243697, 
0.046127729, 0.046011579, 0.045895669, 0.045431661, 0.045276623, 
0.045075832, 0.044674665, 0.044073067, 0.043872654, 0.043672314, 
0.043472039, 0.043271608, 0.042670703, 0.042054135, 0.041845608, 
0.041221108, 0.040804687, 0.040596582, 0.040388757, 0.039765073, 
0.0395571, 0.039349198, 0.039064333, 0.038055023, 0.037802893, 
0.037550885, 0.037298783, 0.036291379, 0.036039671, 0.035788085, 
0.035536405, 0.035284847, 0.035072884, 0.034922698, 0.034847611, 
0.03477254, 0.034546949, 0.034472123, 0.034396881, 0.034321864, 
0.03424664, 0.034150778, 0.034230845, 0.034311107, 0.034391565, 
0.0344718, 0.034792805, 0.034873181, 0.03527484, 0.035279278, 
0.03516246, 0.034928293, 0.034460614, 0.034343839, 0.034226885, 
0.034109976, 0.03364247, 0.033517775, 0.033820972, 0.033881504, 
0.03400293, 0.034063401, 0.034245311, 0.034306118, 0.034366689, 
0.034131359, 0.034039433, 0.033486555, 0.03339433, 0.03330233, 
0.03321014, 0.032802918, 0.032771974, 0.032710129, 0.032585782, 
0.032554731, 0.032523905, 0.032859433, 0.032976441, 0.033093034, 
0.033209632, 0.034027214, 0.034144274, 0.033930496, 0.033972786, 
0.034015232, 0.034057619, 0.034099954, 0.034227058, 0.03426938, 
0.034311863, 0.03439666, 0.034523655, 0.035235152, 0.035666898, 
0.03609875, 0.036386686, 0.03653092, 0.036674977, 0.037107146, 
0.037251344, 0.037090778, 0.037257475, 0.037507508, 0.037674323, 
0.037757893, 0.037841016, 0.038091452, 0.038341829, 0.038535732, 
0.038991997, 0.039144044, 0.039296283, 0.039448495, 0.039600483, 
0.040209464, 0.040514254, 0.040666513, 0.041462915, 0.042818086, 
0.043835301, 0.044174651, 0.044514353, 0.044853778, 0.045193545, 
0.04583851, 0.045641202, 0.045444203, 0.044458868, 0.044261867, 
0.044064962, 0.043868161, 0.043277747, 0.043167303, 0.043071738, 
0.042976412, 0.042880917, 0.042594633, 0.042499269, 0.042308443, 
0.0420414, 0.042128136, 0.04215711, 0.042301696, 0.04235958, 
0.042213482, 0.04176129, 0.041535515, 0.040632408, 0.040406734, 
0.040181207, 0.039955616, 0.039279496, 0.038828785, 0.038543671, 
0.038000767, 0.037819603, 0.037638724, 0.03745792, 0.036734412, 
0.036553775, 0.036373206, 0.036192511, 0.036291896, 0.036100361, 
0.036036636, 0.035972903, 0.035909163, 0.035590326, 0.035526739, 
0.035399131, 0.035185871, 0.035146051, 0.035066413, 0.035026387, 
0.034866909, 0.034826891, 0.034786867, 0.034747051, 0.034881523, 
0.034866512, 0.034851703, 0.034836679, 0.03482185, 0.03477711, 
0.034762047, 0.034747179, 0.034732297, 0.034717416, 0.034672707, 
0.034510906, 0.03469019, 0.034959309), SPRD_MX_USA_5A = c(4.536, 
4.541, 4.634, 4.625, 4.6105, 4.492, 4.4375, 4.4165, 4.4285, 4.466, 
4.4146, 4.4165, 4.4735, 4.482, 4.52, 4.428, 4.366, 4.259, 4.348, 
4.4615, 4.273, 4.3475, 4.247, 4.2695, 4.3095, 4.3315, 4.247, 
4.269, 4.2495, 4.226, 4.23, 4.232, 4.27, 4.284, 4.289, 4.3085, 
4.3445, 4.3445, 4.425, 4.4415, 4.437, 4.473, 4.48, 4.343, 4.305, 
4.3185, 4.344, 4.4085, 4.3485, 4.4035, 4.3195, 4.418, 4.454, 
4.3785, 4.347, 4.3405, 4.375, 4.4275, 4.369, 4.4155, 4.3725, 
4.229, 4.2205, 4.233, 4.2625, 4.2915, 4.3685, 4.261, 4.266, 4.204, 
4.154, 4.186, 4.2365, 4.1825, 4.155, 4.169, 4.17, 4.1242, 4.073, 
4.169, 4.259, 4.248, 4.257, 4.25, 4.1835, 4.1643, 4.2191, 4.25, 
4.242, 4.318, 4.2723, 4.296, 4.304, 4.3186, 4.319, 4.267, 4.2899, 
4.277, 4.3134, 4.351, 4.401, 4.41, 4.41, 4.4095, 4.379, 4.4225, 
4.4589, 4.451, 4.4634, 4.4995, 4.4758, 4.452, 4.454, 4.421, 4.372, 
4.3685, 4.379, 4.3884, 4.419, 4.4915, 4.47, 4.416, 4.374, 4.355, 
4.379, 4.3977, 4.391, 4.4255, 4.4055, 4.4175, 4.393, 4.372, 4.419, 
4.4625, 4.487, 4.441, 4.541, 4.599, 4.614, 4.619, 4.629, 4.603, 
4.635, 4.5725, 4.5226, 4.4909, 4.4797, 4.518, 4.537, 4.552, 4.5395, 
4.5175, 4.4964, 4.5101, 4.538, 4.541, 4.552, 4.588, 4.515, 4.512, 
4.469, 4.5205, 4.493, 4.5075, 4.487, 4.4165, 4.4175, 4.439, 4.4735, 
4.447, 4.43, 4.4435, 4.477, 4.4665, 4.4665, 4.4605, 4.419, 4.444, 
4.421, 4.376, 4.358, 4.2739, 4.131, 4.1536, 4.11, 4.038, 4.03, 
3.955, 3.961, 3.89, 3.824, 3.84, 3.932, 3.9397, 3.853, 3.8461, 
3.905, 3.907, 3.9384, 3.9352, 3.977, 4.008, 4.0185, 4.011, 3.961, 
3.9051, 3.859, 3.869, 3.8667, 3.854, 3.8916, 3.9315, 3.95, 3.92, 
3.9635, 3.952, 3.9745, 3.973, 3.9752, 3.961, 3.909, 3.8015, 3.808, 
3.842, 3.861, 3.8, 3.7771, 3.69, 3.724, 3.725, 3.717, 3.738, 
3.7705, 3.706, 3.7255, 3.725, 3.6575, 3.547, 3.586, 3.622, 3.64, 
3.6625, 3.6345, 3.6695, 3.688, 3.718, 3.768, 3.869, 4.0337, 3.982, 
3.819, 4.0802, 4.202, 4.0645, 4.08, 4.018, 4.091, 4.197, 4.305, 
4.5378, 4.26, 4.3215, 4.3455, 4.134, 4.0735, 4.0784, 4.077, 4.097, 
4.122, 4.105, 3.9904, 3.942, 3.966, 3.892, 3.956, 4.009, 3.941, 
3.827, 3.873, 4.005, 4.124, 4.1721, 4.148, 4.107, 4.0105, 4.0345, 
4.022, 3.935, 3.903, 3.921, 4.066, 4.098, 4.141, 4.246, 4.19, 
4.1345, 4.099, 4.0315, 4.132, 4.213, 4.2414, 4.21, 4.2005, 4.2605, 
4.168, 3.836, 3.741, 3.723, 3.619, 3.6925, 3.72, 3.504, 3.483, 
3.666, 3.757, 3.7975, 3.746, 3.726, 3.685, 3.6655, 3.749, 3.7145, 
3.443, 3.506, 3.575, 3.552, 3.5365, 3.5635, 3.823, 3.797, 3.811, 
3.915, 3.943, 3.9475, 3.953, 3.8955, 3.984, 3.934, 3.934, 3.92, 
3.9495, 3.9002, 3.862, 3.815, 3.849, 3.898, 3.932, 3.881, 3.757, 
3.784, 3.778, 3.706, 3.732, 3.703, 3.673, 3.6765, 3.693, 3.75, 
3.75, 3.764, 3.779, 3.759, 3.784, 3.7815, 3.844, 3.9085, 3.899, 
3.898, 3.905, 3.887, 3.899, 3.889, 3.902, 3.961, 4.013, 3.9795, 
4.153, 4.202, 4.189, 4.065, 4.017, 3.955, 3.9112, 3.873, 3.8785, 
3.854, 3.894, 3.8705, 3.834, 3.835, 3.8825, 3.9185, 3.8817, 3.9055, 
3.909, 3.821, 3.784, 3.788, 3.838, 3.82, 3.692, 3.741, 3.703, 
3.666, 3.668, 3.702, 3.732, 3.684, 3.697, 3.6725, 3.681, 3.7347, 
3.749, 3.7575, 3.749, 3.673, 3.732, 3.701, 3.658, 3.6805, 3.696, 
3.704, 3.702, 3.698, 3.701, 3.6155, 3.623, 3.6232, 3.609, 3.608, 
3.649, 3.616, 3.68, 3.652, 3.625, 3.6195, 3.616, 3.646, 3.6543, 
3.6155, 3.6395, 3.639, 3.645, 3.647, 3.608, 3.2245, 3.2092, 3.2295, 
3.239, 3.282), SPRD_MX_USA_10A = c(4.5215, 4.5195, 4.599, 4.596, 
4.581, 4.44, 4.394, 4.374, 4.3603, 4.363, 4.299, 4.3105, 4.3675, 
4.3695, 4.401, 4.343, 4.305, 4.231, 4.346, 4.4871, 4.341, 4.424, 
4.2985, 4.3165, 4.3558, 4.3785, 4.2845, 4.3245, 4.3171, 4.287, 
4.296, 4.2853, 4.3025, 4.32, 4.2445, 4.2265, 4.283, 4.3, 4.3965, 
4.4639, 4.4425, 4.4915, 4.6255, 4.584, 4.516, 4.4865, 4.48, 4.5795, 
4.509, 4.5661, 4.4575, 4.605, 4.755, 4.683, 4.588, 4.4435, 4.4935, 
4.575, 4.5005, 4.526, 4.4705, 4.202, 4.1975, 4.1799, 4.1775, 
4.2175, 4.291, 4.1155, 4.1095, 4.0117, 3.9625, 4.008, 4.072, 
4.0345, 3.964, 3.9765, 3.9755, 3.9624, 3.8885, 4.0165, 4.1245, 
4.083, 4.061, 4.039, 3.968, 3.9717, 3.9511, 3.971, 3.979, 4.081, 
4.02, 4.0286, 4.042, 4.085, 4.1025, 4.0535, 4.071, 4.051, 4.0811, 
4.1083, 4.158, 4.1605, 4.177, 4.1605, 4.131, 4.1435, 4.185, 4.1811, 
4.19, 4.238, 4.2052, 4.1855, 4.2124, 4.183, 4.088, 4.0675, 4.0995, 
4.1045, 4.1099, 4.159, 4.142, 4.0505, 4, 3.967, 4.0061, 4.051, 
4.052, 4.125, 4.0905, 4.081, 4.0555, 4.031, 4.076, 4.122, 4.1302, 
4.09, 4.1653, 4.2012, 4.2182, 4.202, 4.212, 4.2244, 4.2625, 4.216, 
4.1855, 4.1295, 4.1295, 4.165, 4.201, 4.2017, 4.2062, 4.176, 
4.135, 4.1595, 4.1982, 4.2078, 4.207, 4.2415, 4.1502, 4.143, 
4.1013, 4.1571, 4.1026, 4.1252, 4.056, 4.0025, 4.0025, 4.0106, 
4.0429, 3.9996, 4.013, 4.02, 4.058, 4.009, 4.002, 3.9925, 3.954, 
4.002, 3.978, 3.9476, 3.921, 3.865, 3.72, 3.735, 3.6765, 3.643, 
3.6568, 3.5775, 3.577, 3.5, 3.424, 3.4495, 3.5323, 3.556, 3.4396, 
3.3965, 3.4924, 3.485, 3.505, 3.49, 3.573, 3.582, 3.6085, 3.614, 
3.559, 3.481, 3.422, 3.4195, 3.383, 3.3465, 3.395, 3.4565, 3.509, 
3.4535, 3.518, 3.518, 3.5147, 3.533, 3.533, 3.55, 3.505, 3.3652, 
3.362, 3.423, 3.488, 3.3835, 3.412, 3.304, 3.337, 3.38, 3.326, 
3.346, 3.371, 3.323, 3.349, 3.361, 3.2438, 3.162, 3.199, 3.2365, 
3.234, 3.279, 3.256, 3.322, 3.365, 3.359, 3.4665, 3.561, 3.695, 
3.7065, 3.528, 3.814, 3.9555, 3.7765, 3.753, 3.677, 3.7525, 3.9015, 
4.0485, 4.287, 4.117, 4.196, 4.169, 3.923, 3.83, 3.867, 3.9215, 
3.926, 3.941, 3.9175, 3.7895, 3.7495, 3.7805, 3.685, 3.72, 3.7945, 
3.7005, 3.602, 3.675, 3.783, 3.8945, 3.918, 3.9445, 3.8965, 3.729, 
3.7515, 3.769, 3.7045, 3.6932, 3.6785, 3.8605, 3.875, 3.8855, 
4.039, 3.9795, 3.984, 3.985, 3.917, 3.999, 4.0845, 4.1215, 4.0785, 
4.059, 4.126, 4.066, 3.81, 3.7645, 3.7705, 3.674, 3.721, 3.644, 
3.491, 3.4795, 3.6972, 3.774, 3.866, 3.8215, 3.7955, 3.7435, 
3.7475, 3.8565, 3.8115, 3.629, 3.634, 3.585, 3.5425, 3.5545, 
3.6069, 3.787, 3.784, 3.854, 3.947, 3.934, 3.975, 4.083, 3.992, 
4.0545, 4.0035, 3.986, 3.98, 4.0255, 3.9875, 3.912, 3.874, 3.906, 
3.9575, 3.912, 3.9265, 3.7975, 3.8305, 3.83, 3.784, 3.805, 3.7505, 
3.6955, 3.722, 3.7442, 3.78, 3.787, 3.773, 3.774, 3.731, 3.739, 
3.7335, 3.789, 3.8832, 3.8485, 3.8625, 3.9065, 3.9055, 3.9192, 
3.8895, 3.9265, 3.9659, 4.0665, 4.009, 4.1695, 4.2595, 4.216, 
4.061, 3.9815, 3.905, 3.917, 3.874, 3.857, 3.8622, 3.92, 3.8992, 
3.871, 3.866, 3.8913, 3.9512, 3.913, 3.934, 3.945, 3.8315, 3.786, 
3.8225, 3.8955, 3.861, 3.7615, 3.801, 3.7311, 3.747, 3.768, 3.772, 
3.817, 3.7985, 3.801, 3.7575, 3.75, 3.81, 3.8343, 3.873, 3.883, 
3.795, 3.8555, 3.847, 3.8065, 3.827, 3.8565, 3.8449, 3.8475, 
3.826, 3.848, 3.7355, 3.719, 3.6647, 3.659, 3.6105, 3.6747, 3.647, 
3.701, 3.6645, 3.664, 3.677, 3.695, 3.7325, 3.736, 3.694, 3.7325, 
3.747, 3.7453, 3.73, 3.696, 3.385, 3.419, 3.4355, 3.4515, 3.4925
), UST_2Y = c(0.569, 0.5527, 0.524, 0.552, 0.5522, 0.5545, 0.574, 
0.5795, 0.6055, 0.641, 0.66, 0.6315, 0.566, 0.576, 0.581, 0.581, 
0.5795, 0.6209, 0.631, 0.6115, 0.6045, 0.6005, 0.5875, 0.571, 
0.567, 0.569, 0.562, 0.5606, 0.5655, 0.5665, 0.5727, 0.5755, 
0.5575, 0.5605, 0.5465, 0.543, 0.5465, 0.5515, 0.5645, 0.591, 
0.5895, 0.6095, 0.664, 0.6565, 0.665, 0.6385, 0.6465, 0.6385, 
0.642, 0.639, 0.6225, 0.6165, 0.625, 0.625, 0.6075, 0.574, 0.57, 
0.5955, 0.592, 0.5445, 0.5437, 0.5485, 0.5605, 0.54, 0.5395, 
0.5435, 0.5515, 0.547, 0.546, 0.527, 0.5335, 0.5215, 0.5, 0.4805, 
0.4702, 0.464, 0.4755, 0.446, 0.4435, 0.448, 0.4405, 0.4345, 
0.4425, 0.418, 0.434, 0.437, 0.4471, 0.436, 0.4605, 0.48, 0.4745, 
0.4923, 0.497, 0.4915, 0.4965, 0.4515, 0.4438, 0.4375, 0.4455, 
0.428, 0.402, 0.3991, 0.396, 0.403, 0.4248, 0.4045, 0.3965, 0.3965, 
0.398, 0.3735, 0.382, 0.387, 0.3901, 0.3935, 0.389, 0.396, 0.4025, 
0.421, 0.3992, 0.3664, 0.3695, 0.3815, 0.399, 0.3975, 0.3845, 
0.384, 0.385, 0.3795, 0.368, 0.3626, 0.385, 0.395, 0.4015, 0.396, 
0.389, 0.418, 0.4025, 0.3924, 0.3923, 0.387, 0.382, 0.3795, 0.373, 
0.378, 0.3735, 0.3809, 0.3775, 0.372, 0.367, 0.3765, 0.3765, 
0.3734, 0.3795, 0.3925, 0.386, 0.399, 0.388, 0.376, 0.37, 0.3725, 
0.364, 0.3605, 0.3574, 0.3535, 0.3535, 0.3785, 0.394, 0.398, 
0.4015, 0.41, 0.4125, 0.4045, 0.3925, 0.3915, 0.391, 0.3837, 
0.397, 0.3865, 0.3771, 0.385, 0.375, 0.405, 0.395, 0.3937, 0.394, 
0.4325, 0.442, 0.437, 0.434, 0.423, 0.4295, 0.411, 0.408, 0.4045, 
0.4223, 0.4307, 0.4253, 0.425, 0.415, 0.4005, 0.3864, 0.395, 
0.3828, 0.376, 0.3735, 0.382, 0.394, 0.3985, 0.3938, 0.395, 0.4017, 
0.392, 0.422, 0.416, 0.4255, 0.4267, 0.4293, 0.4165, 0.42, 0.409, 
0.376, 0.381, 0.3713, 0.3724, 0.368, 0.3678, 0.37, 0.3615, 0.3635, 
0.36, 0.363, 0.359, 0.3463, 0.348, 0.342, 0.3379, 0.364, 0.359, 
0.371, 0.3804, 0.3871, 0.3815, 0.3733, 0.3869, 0.383, 0.3945, 
0.399, 0.407, 0.4585, 0.455, 0.4645, 0.4847, 0.501, 0.5, 0.4444, 
0.4305, 0.4263, 0.4239, 0.4727, 0.5088, 0.5795, 0.5835, 0.5335, 
0.511, 0.5174, 0.5226, 0.551, 0.522, 0.585, 0.5391, 0.4982, 0.527, 
0.51, 0.475, 0.4796, 0.474, 0.478, 0.4848, 0.5089, 0.4771, 0.4775, 
0.478, 0.4775, 0.499, 0.4791, 0.4842, 0.48, 0.48, 0.475, 0.4807, 
0.5045, 0.5265, 0.53, 0.5442, 0.5274, 0.5546, 0.58, 0.5603, 0.548, 
0.5365, 0.5574, 0.565, 0.568, 0.5885, 0.626, 0.6015, 0.6218, 
0.5957, 0.593, 0.531, 0.4835, 0.4959, 0.4878, 0.4805, 0.47, 0.4604, 
0.4665, 0.4495, 0.463, 0.4713, 0.502, 0.4875, 0.48, 0.4798, 0.448, 
0.428, 0.441, 0.4377, 0.431, 0.433, 0.431, 0.422, 0.4099, 0.4045, 
0.423, 0.4395, 0.41, 0.397, 0.375, 0.3788, 0.378, 0.3755, 0.374, 
0.378, 0.377, 0.384, 0.381, 0.386, 0.3985, 0.395, 0.3938, 0.427, 
0.424, 0.403, 0.44, 0.454, 0.476, 0.49, 0.498, 0.4847, 0.477, 
0.482, 0.4901, 0.5105, 0.5, 0.5465, 0.4915, 0.4765, 0.5, 0.5195, 
0.511, 0.51, 0.514, 0.5025, 0.4899, 0.496, 0.4595, 0.4335, 0.441, 
0.4415, 0.4535, 0.424, 0.451, 0.462, 0.438, 0.434, 0.4515, 0.4575, 
0.453, 0.4565, 0.4489, 0.438, 0.4445, 0.4497, 0.443, 0.466, 0.478, 
0.506, 0.483, 0.4826, 0.55, 0.5638, 0.57, 0.563, 0.5723, 0.551, 
0.5726, 0.5775, 0.537, 0.5255, 0.4965, 0.4906, 0.5055, 0.5096, 
0.52, 0.5476, 0.5373, 0.546, 0.5406, 0.545, 0.543, 0.546, 0.553, 
0.531, 0.534, 0.561, 0.535, 0.521, 0.539, 0.52, 0.496, 0.509, 
0.489, 0.491, 0.502, 0.504, 0.504, 0.508, 0.492, 0.507, 0.513, 
0.527, 0.537, 0.5345, 0.5235, 0.543, 0.566, 0.5775, 0.596, 0.617
)), row.names = c("2012-02-28", "2012-02-29", "2012-03-02", "2012-03-05", 
"2012-03-06", "2012-03-07", "2012-03-09", "2012-03-12", "2012-03-13", 
"2012-03-14", "2012-03-20", "2012-03-21", "2012-03-27", "2012-03-28", 
"2012-03-29", "2012-03-30", "2012-04-02", "2012-04-03", "2012-04-05", 
"2012-04-06", "2012-04-09", "2012-04-10", "2012-04-11", "2012-04-12", 
"2012-04-13", "2012-04-16", "2012-04-17", "2012-04-18", "2012-04-19", 
"2012-04-20", "2012-04-23", "2012-04-24", "2012-04-25", "2012-04-26", 
"2012-05-02", "2012-05-03", "2012-05-04", "2012-05-07", "2012-05-08", 
"2012-05-09", "2012-05-10", "2012-05-11", "2012-05-15", "2012-05-17", 
"2012-05-18", "2012-05-21", "2012-05-22", "2012-05-23", "2012-05-24", 
"2012-05-25", "2012-05-29", "2012-05-30", "2012-06-01", "2012-06-04", 
"2012-06-05", "2012-06-08", "2012-06-11", "2012-06-13", "2012-06-14", 
"2012-06-15", "2012-06-18", "2012-06-20", "2012-06-21", "2012-06-22", 
"2012-06-26", "2012-06-27", "2012-06-28", "2012-06-29", "2012-07-02", 
"2012-07-04", "2012-07-05", "2012-07-06", "2012-07-11", "2012-07-12", 
"2012-07-13", "2012-07-16", "2012-07-17", "2012-07-19", "2012-07-20", 
"2012-07-23", "2012-07-24", "2012-07-25", "2012-07-27", "2012-07-30", 
"2012-08-01", "2012-08-02", "2012-08-03", "2012-08-06", "2012-08-07", 
"2012-08-09", "2012-08-14", "2012-08-15", "2012-08-16", "2012-08-20", 
"2012-08-21", "2012-08-24", "2012-08-27", "2012-08-28", "2012-08-29", 
"2012-08-30", "2012-08-31", "2012-09-03", "2012-09-04", "2012-09-05", 
"2012-09-06", "2012-09-07", "2012-09-10", "2012-09-11", "2012-09-12", 
"2012-09-13", "2012-09-17", "2012-09-18", "2012-09-19", "2012-09-20", 
"2012-09-21", "2012-09-24", "2012-09-25", "2012-09-26", "2012-09-27", 
"2012-10-01", "2012-10-03", "2012-10-04", "2012-10-05", "2012-10-08", 
"2012-10-09", "2012-10-10", "2012-10-11", "2012-10-12", "2012-10-15", 
"2012-10-16", "2012-10-17", "2012-10-18", "2012-10-19", "2012-10-23", 
"2012-10-24", "2012-10-25", "2012-10-26", "2012-10-29", "2012-10-30", 
"2012-10-31", "2012-11-01", "2012-11-02", "2012-11-05", "2012-11-07", 
"2012-11-08", "2012-11-09", "2012-11-12", "2012-11-13", "2012-11-14", 
"2012-11-15", "2012-11-16", "2012-11-19", "2012-11-20", "2012-11-21", 
"2012-11-22", "2012-11-26", "2012-11-27", "2012-11-29", "2012-11-30", 
"2012-12-03", "2012-12-04", "2012-12-05", "2012-12-07", "2012-12-10", 
"2012-12-12", "2012-12-17", "2012-12-18", "2012-12-19", "2012-12-20", 
"2012-12-25", "2012-12-26", "2012-12-27", "2012-12-28", "2012-12-31", 
"2013-01-01", "2013-01-02", "2013-01-03", "2013-01-08", "2013-01-09", 
"2013-01-11", "2013-01-15", "2013-01-17", "2013-01-21", "2013-01-22", 
"2013-01-24", "2013-01-25", "2013-01-28", "2013-01-29", "2013-01-31", 
"2013-02-01", "2013-02-05", "2013-02-06", "2013-02-07", "2013-02-08", 
"2013-02-12", "2013-02-13", "2013-02-15", "2013-02-18", "2013-02-20", 
"2013-02-22", "2013-02-25", "2013-02-27", "2013-02-28", "2013-03-01", 
"2013-03-04", "2013-03-06", "2013-03-07", "2013-03-08", "2013-03-12", 
"2013-03-13", "2013-03-14", "2013-03-15", "2013-03-19", "2013-03-20", 
"2013-03-21", "2013-03-22", "2013-03-26", "2013-03-28", "2013-03-29", 
"2013-04-01", "2013-04-05", "2013-04-08", "2013-04-11", "2013-04-12", 
"2013-04-15", "2013-04-16", "2013-04-17", "2013-04-22", "2013-04-23", 
"2013-04-24", "2013-04-25", "2013-04-26", "2013-04-29", "2013-04-30", 
"2013-05-01", "2013-05-02", "2013-05-07", "2013-05-09", "2013-05-10", 
"2013-05-13", "2013-05-14", "2013-05-15", "2013-05-16", "2013-05-20", 
"2013-05-21", "2013-05-22", "2013-05-23", "2013-05-27", "2013-05-31", 
"2013-06-03", "2013-06-04", "2013-06-07", "2013-06-11", "2013-06-12", 
"2013-06-13", "2013-06-14", "2013-06-17", "2013-06-18", "2013-06-19", 
"2013-06-20", "2013-06-24", "2013-06-25", "2013-06-26", "2013-06-28", 
"2013-07-01", "2013-07-02", "2013-07-03", "2013-07-04", "2013-07-05", 
"2013-07-08", "2013-07-11", "2013-07-12", "2013-07-15", "2013-07-17", 
"2013-07-18", "2013-07-19", "2013-07-22", "2013-07-23", "2013-07-24", 
"2013-07-25", "2013-07-29", "2013-07-30", "2013-07-31", "2013-08-01", 
"2013-08-05", "2013-08-06", "2013-08-07", "2013-08-08", "2013-08-09", 
"2013-08-12", "2013-08-14", "2013-08-15", "2013-08-16", "2013-08-19", 
"2013-08-20", "2013-08-21", "2013-08-22", "2013-08-23", "2013-08-26", 
"2013-08-27", "2013-08-28", "2013-08-29", "2013-08-30", "2013-09-03", 
"2013-09-04", "2013-09-09", "2013-09-10", "2013-09-11", "2013-09-13", 
"2013-09-17", "2013-09-18", "2013-09-19", "2013-09-20", "2013-09-24", 
"2013-09-25", "2013-09-30", "2013-10-01", "2013-10-03", "2013-10-04", 
"2013-10-07", "2013-10-08", "2013-10-09", "2013-10-14", "2013-10-15", 
"2013-10-21", "2013-10-22", "2013-10-23", "2013-10-24", "2013-10-29", 
"2013-10-30", "2013-11-01", "2013-11-05", "2013-11-06", "2013-11-07", 
"2013-11-11", "2013-11-12", "2013-11-13", "2013-11-14", "2013-11-21", 
"2013-11-22", "2013-11-25", "2013-11-26", "2013-11-27", "2013-11-28", 
"2013-11-29", "2013-12-02", "2013-12-03", "2013-12-04", "2013-12-06", 
"2013-12-09", "2013-12-10", "2013-12-13", "2013-12-16", "2013-12-18", 
"2013-12-19", "2013-12-20", "2013-12-23", "2013-12-24", "2013-12-25", 
"2013-12-27", "2013-12-30", "2014-01-01", "2014-01-02", "2014-01-03", 
"2014-01-06", "2014-01-09", "2014-01-10", "2014-01-13", "2014-01-14", 
"2014-01-15", "2014-01-16", "2014-01-17", "2014-01-21", "2014-01-23", 
"2014-01-24", "2014-01-27", "2014-01-31", "2014-02-03", "2014-02-04", 
"2014-02-05", "2014-02-06", "2014-02-07", "2014-02-11", "2014-02-12", 
"2014-02-13", "2014-02-18", "2014-02-19", "2014-02-20", "2014-02-21", 
"2014-02-24", "2014-02-25", "2014-02-26", "2014-02-27", "2014-02-28", 
"2014-03-03", "2014-03-04", "2014-03-06", "2014-03-10", "2014-03-13", 
"2014-03-14", "2014-03-19", "2014-03-21", "2014-03-25", "2014-03-27", 
"2014-03-28", "2014-04-01", "2014-04-02", "2014-04-03", "2014-04-04", 
"2014-04-07", "2014-04-09", "2014-04-11", "2014-04-14", "2014-04-15", 
"2014-04-16", "2014-04-17", "2014-04-21", "2014-04-22", "2014-04-23", 
"2014-04-24", "2014-04-25", "2014-04-28", "2014-04-29", "2014-04-30", 
"2014-05-01", "2014-05-06", "2014-05-07", "2014-05-09", "2014-05-12", 
"2014-05-13", "2014-05-15", "2014-05-16", "2014-05-20", "2014-05-21", 
"2014-05-22", "2014-05-23", "2014-05-26", "2014-05-27", "2014-05-28", 
"2014-05-29", "2014-05-30", "2014-06-02", "2014-06-03", "2014-06-04", 
"2014-06-05", "2014-06-06", "2014-06-09", "2014-06-11", "2014-06-13", 
"2014-06-16"), class = "data.frame")
```

The graph of the predictions vs actual values using the **test set** is the following

[with test set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lal24.jpg)

But when I use another set with the same features in another dates (different values) I got this

[with another data but same features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bTo6.jpg)

I appreciate that someone could help me.

Comment: Are you sure it is the same data? What did you expect? In essence, there are a few factors that come into play; did you predefine your `folds`? Did you use the same `seed`?

How about the data itself, is it on the same scales? Provide some data for us, so we can have a look....

Comment: @Serkan Yes I'm sure is the same data, and I expected that the fit in the "extra data" was the same as in the first graph. For define the `cv.folds` I use a loop to choose the best hyper parameters (hyper grid) and yes, I use the same seed with `set.seed()` function, I put it before the `gbm` function and before the `predict` function. I edit the question to put 500 of the 1500 rows of data, that is all that leaves me write. I would appreciate it if you could take a look

Comment: It looks like your model is over-fitted.

Comment: @programandoconro if its over-fitted why in the first test set shows a good fit, but in another set doesn't?

Comment: This is quite interesting for me. If you indeed used the same data, and you are absolutely sure that there is no data-leak, or coding errors - then Im not sure why you see what you do. What is the `RMSE` of the different predictions?